# Squirrel sql client 3.7 on Mac OSX 10.11 and Ubuntu 15.10 has no drivers installed

Tags: ubuntu, osx-yosemite, squirrel-sql

Here is my problem.
I am installing Squirrel SQL Client 3.7 on a Mac and an Ubuntu computers.
After executing

```
java -jar squirrel-sql-3.7-MACOSX-install.jar
```

All drivers are marked with and "x" on a red circle.
Even when I am specifically requesting the MS SQL driver to be installed.
And I don't even need all those drivers, all I need is to access a MS SQL database.

Any help for fixing this issue on a Mac and/or Ubuntu will be much appreciated, most preferable Ubuntu.

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. We are not general software tech support.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I gave up and installed RazorSQL.